# Preapproval API scenario in trial credit scenario

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

We want to offer a online service that uses a credit system.

Initially we want to offer x amount of credits as a free trial. To activate this trial the user agrees to a subscription via PayPal (but does not pay anything at that time)

1) Is it possible to set up using Preapproval API, if not is there a better suited API

2) Can it be setup through PayPal so that the user does not need an existing PayPal account or  to create a new one. If there is a way to do this other than preapproval API please let me know as well.

3) We want the billing to be automatic when the user credits run out. Therefore there is no set time, e.g 1 month, when each user is charged. Is this possible?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few different options:

1. Reference Transactions (no cost requires approval from PayPal)
2. Enhanced Recurring Billing/Automatic Payments (cannot be used with a Pro or Advanced Accounts) Has a cost associated with it ($19.99 monthly)
3. Recurring Billing with PayPal Payments Pro Payflow or PayPal Payments Advanced. Has a cost associated with it ($10.00 monthly in addition to the cost of the Payflow/Advanced account)

Here are the details from the three different options:

**Reference Transactions**, which does require that you call into PayPal Customer Support and that your account is approved for this feature.

Reference transactions does allow for guest checkout billing.

From the PayPal Documentation, Recurring payments using reference transactions enable you to handle payments for varying amounts of money on a varying schedule.

[Reference Transaction Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/)

**Enhanced Recurring Billing/Automatic Billing**

If you do not plan to uses PayPal Payments Pro or Advanced at any time you can get setup with Enhanced Recurring Billing/ Automatic Billing

[Automatic Billing Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/autobill_buttons/)

From the PayPal Documentation:

You can create Automatic Billing buttons for your website by using a tool on the PayPal website. If you're a power user, you can write the HTML code for PayPal hosted Automatic Billing buttons yourself.

With Automatic Billing buttons, buyers agree to pay you automatically when you bill them, up to a limit that they choose. You set the parameters for the limits they choose. Automatic billing allows Guest Checkout, so you can bill a credit card.

**PayPal Payments Pro Payflow/Advanced**

For PayPal Payments Pro Payflow/Advanced you can setup Recurring Billing as well. Payflow Pro allows you to process credit cards directly. Here is the information on Recurring Billing through Payflow:

[Payflow Recurring Billing](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. Assuming money is not a problem on our side - which of the options here is the simplest to set up? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, would these options allow to set up subscription without an initial first payment?

Comment: Enhanced Recurring Payments and Recurring Payments through Payflow/Advanced allows you to have a trial period. Enhanced Recurring is most likely the easiest to setup, but once you add Enhanced Recurring Billing to any PayPal account you cannot upgrade to Pro/Payflow/Advanced. It requires you to create a new PayPal account if you ever want to upgrade to Pro/Payflow/Advanced.

Comment: Hi, Looking at the enhanced recurring payments and Recurring Payments through Payflow/Advanced, you can only bill users once per month? Is there not a way that allows automatic billing multiple times per month? Thanks for you help.

Comment: You can setup automatic billing through Enhanced Recurring Billing allowing you to bill multiple times varying amounts.